# why I get undefined is not a constructor while using firestore Geopoint?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I am building an app using React native , I have to insert geo coordinates into my firestore database , I am using firebase , firestore and geofirestore , I have followed some tutorials , but
still can not make this work , could you plase help , here is my code :

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import  firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import * as geofirestore from 'geofirestore';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';




 const GeoFirestore = geofirestore.initializeApp(firebase.firestore());

    const lat = 35.19580846863968;
    const long = -3.911421988159418;
  
              const geocollection=GeoFirestore.collection("mycollection");
                    await geocollection.add({
                    title: title,
                   timestamps: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                   price : price,
                   coordinates : new firebase.firestore.GeohPoint(40.7589, -73.9851),
                   climatisation: aclimatisation,
                   images:  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({...downloadUrls}),
```

and the error that its firing is :

> [TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new
> _app.default.firestore.GeohPoint(40.7589, -73.9851)'

Comment: I think you have a typo in ```firebase.firestore.GeohPoint``` ?

Comment: You can post your own answer so that other community members that have the same issue can easily see it. Please check: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

as said and found by @sushrut619 it was a typo error , such a ridiculous mistake ,  GeoPoint in stead of

> GeohPoint